# Iterating rasters using parse path in complex model in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, iteration, file-path

I have a complex model (with many tools/steps chained - named from "a" to "p") and I need iterate two input rasters (p1.img and p2.img), so that all the model outputs returned for the two input files. As there are many chained steps on the model, I applied the Parse Path output as a in-line variable substituition. My attempts and the problem were:

1. Multivalue iterator: return the outputs correctly but just in relation the file p1.img, doesn't run for the file p2.img. (image below)
2. Raster iterator: generate a kind of loop, running repeatedly and cumulatively outputs in relation of the file p1.img. (image below)
3. Turn the raster iterator and parse path tools as a submodel and add it into a main model that contain the steps:  return the outputs correctly but just in relation the file p1.img, doesn't run for the file p2.img. (image below)

How can I run all the model steps for both input files p1 and p2?

I suspect that the problem is the Parse Path tool, that in some way limit the model to run upon the first file (p1) only.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To progress this question I think we need to investigate using test models that only include the minimum number of tools to reproduce your problem, rather than using your actual models.